# Convert Data.Sequence to a List?

Tags: haskell

Is there a generally accepted way of converting a Data.Sequence (Seq a) to a list [a]?

I see there's a fromList, but no toList

Comment: I am going to teach you how to fish: If you go to [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and search for [`Seq a -> [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Seq+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) (the type signature of the function you want), the first hit is the `toList` function dbaupp mentions. Hoogle isn't always able to find what you want, but it is always worth checking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) instance for `Seq a`, and this provides a [`toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) method. e.g. this will print [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

```
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Sequence (fromList)

main = print . toList . fromList $ [1..10]
```

Comment: The most important part of this answer is: Don't ignore instance lists! They are often really important for the full API for a type.